# WCF service URL ACL on windows 7 : Your process does not have access rights to this namespace

Tags: wcf, http, windows-7, namespaces

Porting an application from my previous development machine (XP) to a new one (w7), and having an issue with WCF.

> HTTP could not register URL
>   http://+:8001/KolonistenVanCatan/MetaData/.
>   Your process does not have access
>   rights to this namespace (see
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=70353
>   for details).

Now, the page referred to, and many blogs all explain the same solution, which I understand, but whenever trying to add the url, and entering my account name, it says the parameter is incorrect.

> netsh http add urlacl
>   url=http://+8001/KolonistenVanCatan/MetaData
>   user=SDRY\SXXXX DX RXXXX

Is this not working because of the spaces in my windows account name ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just place the user name into quotes like `user="SDRY\SXXXX DX RXXXX"`